# Should the tag "bulbs" relate to things like Springtime flowers or root vegetables?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently the tag [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs) is mostly associated with "Onions", a bulb vegetable that is strictly speaking a subset of ["Root Vegetables"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_root_vegetables).

Personally when I think of [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs) in a gardening context, the first thing that comes to mind is Springtime bulbs (flowers):

- Crocus.
- Daffodils.
- Tulips.

And other flowering plants like:

- Iris.
- Lilies.
- Daylilies.

Personally I think the tag [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs) would be better served if it was associated with flowering type plants (as per above).

Additionally it might be worthwhile to make "bulb-vegetables" a synonym of [root-vegetables](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-vegetables)

**Q.** What are other peoples thoughts on this, do you agree or disagree?

**Q.** Is there a better way of handling these kind of conflicts?

Back story to the above can be found **[here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1795605#1795605)** (within [The Garden Shed](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/546/the-garden-shed))

Answer (score 3):

The onion **is** a bulb - as is garlic, wild onion (not all of which are edible, so are these your springtime bulbs?), etc. There are quite a few edible plants grown as ornamentals and vice versa.

There are going to be lots of these potentially ambiguous classifications. I think you're over complicating matters.

if you really want to divide bulbs up, then what about bulbs-flowering, and bulbs-edible? Someone growing wild onions or garlic, or wishing to eat their daffodil flowers will have decide what to do when the time comes (if it ever does!).

Comment: I agree and I'm **not** saying an onion isn't a bulb. The point of my question is, I believe (rightly or wrongly) most people think Springtime flowers (flowering plants) when "bulbs" are mentioned in a gardening context...

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the tag bulbs and add tag onion/shallot/whatevertheyare and tag [Allium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium) because most onion/garlic thing are under the genus [Allium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allium)