# How to group questions on sexual reproduction

Tags: discussion, tags

I want to search for all questions about plant sexual reproduction, and the breeding of plants/cultivars via sexual reproduction as opposed to asexual reproduction or cloning (striking cuttings). Is it okay to add a tag for this? Should it be called [sexual-reproduction](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-reproduction) or does someone have a better idea? Perhaps [breeding](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/breeding)?

Are there any existing questions on cross-breeding to produce new cultivars?

Comment: I might be wrong here, but isn't sexual reproduction served by [tag:pollination] and the asexual ones by [tag:grafting] and [tag:cuttings]. To me, "sexual-reproduction" seems more botanical than gardening. For example, a lay person wouldn't think of searching for that, if they're thinking of pollinating their cherry tree successfully...

Comment: Damn. I agree, but somehow I couldn't think of the right word. Can someone make one a synonym of the other please? :$

Comment: Sure, I'll make it a synonym, but I'll have to rollback your recent changes. This is to avoid having to "merge" the tags (which, I believe, is irreversible), whereas a simple synonym can be spliced any time. The tag support is still a bit fragile. It's possible I'm wrong here, but better safe than sorry...

Comment: No problems ...

Comment: Thanks, it's done now. I've posted an answer so that it can be marked as resolved (else Community ♦ will bump it up in a month's time)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We already have the [pollination](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pollination) tag, which is equivalent to sexual-reproduction. I think the distinction is primarily botanical, and we've always leaned towards the gardening usage rather than the botanical one. For example, [root-vegetables](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/root-vegetables) for onions & garlic, [bulbs](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bulbs) for [dahlias and other flowering plants, instead of onions](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/q/243/109), (although there might be a few tagged for onions by moi, which should be removed).

So I don't think it is necessary for the [sexual-reproduction](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexual-reproduction) tag. However, I've made it a synonym of [pollination](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pollination) as per your request in the comments above.